# Add a relationship without data already in the database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It appears that I can't add a relationship unless there is already some data in some Entities that obey that relationship. Is this correct? I want to be able to set up my relationships and Labels first and then populate with data and have the data just use the relationships.

I am using:

```
MATCH (from:this_label),(to:that_label)
WHERE from.id = to.uuid
CREATE (from)-[:hasARelationship]->(to);
```

Basically, I want to be able to define a bunch of relationships on nodes of a certain label, even if those node-type do not yet exist. And then when some data of those nodes comes into the database it will hook up the relationships automatically.

Comment: What does it mean for Entities to obey relationships? Does "node-type" mean a node with a label?

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a constraint on a label, enforcing that nodes with that label have a relationship of a certain type to a particular node (or any node with a particular label). Is this what you want?

Comment: @jjaderberg yes, that sounds about right. I haven't heard about constraints  on labels. thanks

Comment: Constraints on relationships / cardinalities are on the roadmap but not implemented yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to distinguish between the responsibilities of *enforcing a constraint* and *fulfilling a constraint*.

Neo4j allows for indices and constraints associated with labels. Indices and constraints created for a label are used to index and constrain the nodes that have that label. As of [version 2.2.5](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/graphdb-neo4j.html#graphdb-neo4j-schema-constraints), there is only one type of constraint: a uniqueness constraint for a single property. There have been talk about adding constraints for combinations of properties, and for relationships, but I don't know the status of these conversations.

The Neo4j schema constraints *enforce* something, but they will not *fulfill*, in the sense of changing your operations on the database to satisfy the constraint. If there were constraints enforcing that a node with label `A` may only be created if it has a relationship of type `R` to a node with label `B`, they would block your operation if it did not satisfy the constraint, but they would not satisfy it for you.

The best way to achieve this is a) to satisfy this requirement in your client application, or b) to create an extension for Neo4j. For an extension example, consider [neo4j-uuid](https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-uuid) by Stefan Armbruster. It listens to transactions (using what's called a `TransactionEventListener`) and makes sure that any node that is created in the database has a UUID. This extension *satisfies* what could only be *enforced* by a corresponding Neo4j schema constraint (there are other differences, e.g., the constraint would be limited to the scope of a label).

A way to achieve your intention could be to either create an extension which listens to what you write to the database and satisfies your constraint, altering your operations if necessary; or, one which provides an invocation target in the server (a RESTful endpoint) that you can invoke whenever you want to create a node with a particular label. The extension would then create the node and other elements necessary to fulfill your schema. A downside to the former could be the overhead of listening to all your operations, a downside to the latter could be that it breaks your flow of interaction with the database to introduce a separate type of invocation (e.g., if you normally execute cypher statements and have to pause to issue a separate `POST` request and interpret the response before continuing).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `MERGE` instead of `MATCH`.

```
MERGE (from:this_label) -[:hasARelationship]-> (to:that_label) WHERE from.id = to.uuid
```

If you are trying to create relationships without nodes, I guess that is not even possible in NEO4J. Infact, it wouldn't be possible in any graph in general.

Comment: So?? Sorry, but what exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to be able to set up relationships first, and then when Nodes are created that fit the relationship they are connected. At the moment, I can't

Comment: thanks , but why would it not be possible? It is basically just a relationship schema - if you see a Node with this label and this attributes, then apply this relationship.. can't something like that be done?

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to pre-populate your DB with relationships that connect to dummy nodes. Among the many reasons are these:

- You would not be able to make any meaningful queries involving such relationships
- Trying to fill in the dummy nodes later on with actual data may be a complex endeavor
- It is very easy to created relationships right when they are needed. neo4j is a "schemaless" DB (except when you define uniqueness constraints, as @jjaderberg mentions). You can create a relationship of any type connecting nodes with any labels (or no labels) at any time. To keep things organized, you may choose to write your DB client code and Cypher queries to conform to your own conceptual "schema", but neo4j has no such a requirement.

Comment: thanks, so how does one set a schema to force nodes of a certain type to have a relationship with other nodes?

Comment: neo4j is a "schemaless" DB. There is no preset schema. You can create a relationship of any type connecting nodes with any labels (or no labels) at any time. You may choose to impose your own "schema" by writing your code as if there was one, but neo4j does not impose such a requirement.